# Do I need USB isolator for laptop computer?

Tags: opto-isolator, usb-hub

I have a product which is powered from main AC power. I need to serial communicate the product with a computer, for example sending some bytes to the product by the terminal program in the computer. I have a USB-to-UART converter to communicate with the product. However I worry that the AC power from the product will damage my computer's USB port. If I am using a laptop computer powered by the battery (not the AC main), do I still need a USB isolator to connect the USB-to-UART converter to my laptop computer?

Please provide reason instead of just answering yes or no.
Thank you very much.

Comment: An isolator will last you until USB becomes obsolete, and you'll never need to wonder whether or not you'll need one since you'll already have one. That said, it's much cheaper to isolate the UART part than the USB part.

Comment: Because I do not have one USB isolator or UART isolator in hand now, it may take 3 days to ship to me if I buy one now. However I need to communicate with the product tomorrow, so I am thinking if it is possible that I do not need an isolator if the laptop is run by battery.

Comment: Indeed operating your laptop computer on battery will ensure that  it cannot be damaged by any fault, ground loop, etc.  And chances are that there is no risk anyway unless your mystery "product" is some oddball, legacy and/or dodgy gadget that may have power or grounding problems. (In which case it wouldn't be very safe to use even if you weren't connecting it to a computer)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you consider isolating the RS-232 as @Ignacio suggests. You can even buy a packaged [single-chip solution](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM3251E.pdf) that actually includes internal transformers for signal **and** power isolation:

[image]

A USB port in your unit with a connection to the mains is an extremely dangerous thing to manufacture- someday someone may plug something into that plug that will kill them or destroy a desktop computer.

With a laptop computer, depending on how it connects to the mains, touching the shell on another USB plug or headphone jack etc. when removing it or plugging it in could kill someone. This has happened for real, it is not just a theoretical risk.

Comment: If it's TTL UART rather than full RS-232 then a couple of optocouplers will be enough to isolate.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sure, especially if the other side can be powered off the USB.

Comment: I am not designing a circuit for the product. Actually I am going to test a product with a UART port. I have a UART-to-USB converter in hand, I am thinking if it is possible that I connect the converter to the laptop directly. Because it will takes 3 days to ship the isolator to us if I buy it now, but we want to do it tomorrow. In fact we will use a AC power source instead of the wall main AC power. And the guy who are going to test it is an engineer.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Oh you remain me something. I have an old circuit with optocouplers to communicate with the RS-485, I can just change it to TTL UART. Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Either way, please use an isolator.